# about certification in java

Tags: java

i want to know,what is basic certification in Java and what is the syllabus for it?.pls tell me.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042248/java-certification-roadmap

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about certification and not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier it was **SCJA** now **Oracle Certified Associate**.Book written by **Cameron McKenzie** covers all topics.

Answer (score 4):

Its called ***Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 5/SE 6*** formerly called ***SCJA***.

More details [here](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=319).

Comment: "Certified oracle" would be such a catchier title. :)

Answer (score 0):

SCJA = Sun Certified Java Associate

More info is here: http://www.whizlabs.com/jwhiz.html

Comment: That name is a bit outdated now that Oracle has taken over things.

Answer (score 0):

SCJA (OCAJ) is the basic Certification in Java, this certification gives you the knowledge to manage a Java project.

for more information read this [**SCJA preparation**](http://www.epractizelabs.com/blog2/?p=51) article.

This **[Java Certification](http://www.epractizelabs.com/oracle/java-certifications/index.html)** Page to know the Certification available in Oracle for Java.